# How can I dump GENERIC tree from gfortran

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, gfortran

As far as I know gfortran's key `-fdump-tree-original` means "Dump global namespace's `gfc_code` and it's children".
However, also AFAIK, the `gfc_code`s are transformed to `GENERIC` intermediate representation. So the question is: How can I dump it, with which key? Or I should attach a debugger to `f951` process?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you are asking where to use the key `-fdump-tree-original`? That would be at compilation: `gfortran -fdump-tree-original file.f90`. That produces a file named `file.f90.003t.original` (or something similar) that you can open with your favorite editor.

Comment: No. I mean there are two tree representations in gfortran. One of them is original (in gfc-internals documentation it named as gfc_code), the other is GENERIC. The middle-end works with GENERIC. So, I want to dump GENERIC tree, not original.

Comment: I see. I do not know much about the GENERIC format, but you can see if the flag `fdump-tree-all` gives you what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. For the gfc_code tree to dump the -fdump-parse-tree key should be used. To dump the GENERIC tree I should use the -fdump-tree-original key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use `-fdump-tree-original` key.